# How to replace specific values a variable takes through a loop in Stata

Tags: loops, stata

I am looking to replace a list of variables that take string value `"NR"` with missing. The command is `replace`. However, the `foreach` loop for the varlist does not seem to be working. After running and reviewing the dataset, the values are still `"NR"` instead of "."

Code:

```
local vars fpl_100_150 fpl_150_200 fpl_200_250 

foreach var of local vars {
    replace 'var' = "." if 'var' == "NR"
}
```

Comment: "does not seem to be working" is odd wording as on the face of it your loop will trigger an error message, as @TheIceBear explains nicely.

Answer (score 1):

Two things.

First, the error in your code is that you reference the local `var` created in `foreach var of local vars {` as `'var'` and not `` `var' ``. So the fix to the error you are getting would be this:

```
local vars fpl_100_150 fpl_150_200 fpl_200_250 

foreach var of local vars {
    replace `var' = "." if `var' == "NR"
}
```

Additionally, the convention for missing string values in Stata is the empty string `""`. `.` is the convention to represent missing numeric values. This becomes relevant when Stata commands test a variable such as with `missing(fpl_100_150 )`. That syntax is commonly used inside other commands: the function `missing()` classifies `"."` as not missing but `""` as missing. Therefore I suggest that you change the line inside the loop to `` replace `var' = "" if `var' == "NR" ``.

Comment: Very helpful! Interestingly the numeric values can take a value of NR if the data were not collected per specifications in this dataset and great to keep in mind for future analysis.